# How would I get this program to print out 3 random bars of asterisks all adding up to the specified number?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;    
public class BarChart {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rgen = new Random();

        int number;
        int ast;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        int count3 = 0;

        System.out.print("How many integers should be generated? ");
        number = keyboard.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++){ 
            ast = rgen.nextInt(3);
            count1++;
            System.out.print("*"); 
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            ast = rgen.nextInt(2);
            count2++;
            System.out.print("*"); 
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            ast = rgen.nextInt(1);
            count3++;
            System.out.print("*"); 
        }

        number = count1 + count2 + count3;  
    }
}
```

I am new to this and I need to make a program using for loops that asks the user for a positive number, then 3 bars of asterisks get printed out that all equal the number the user types. For example:

```
How many integers should be generated? 32

************** 14
****** 6
************ 12
```

Comment: It will be 3 bars every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
count1 = rgen.nextInt(number);
for(int x=0; x<count1; x++) {
  system.out.print("*");
}
system.out.println(count1);    

count2 = rgen.nextInt(number-count1);
for(int x=0; x<count2; x++) {
  system.out.print("*");
}
system.out.println(count2);

count3 = number-(count1+count2);
for(int x=0; x<count3; x++) {
  system.out.print("*");
}
system.out.println(count3);
```

Hope this works.